# PyOpenGL isnt a package

Tags: python, pyopengl

Trying to run a basic pygame based PyOpenGL window and it returns an error.

I have reinstalled them both from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Code:

```
import pygame as pg
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GL'; 'OpenGL' is not a package
```

Tried running it, expected a window with a blue/grey background. recieved an error in VS Code terminal and anger

Comment: You could try downloading your libraries from a reasonably official source like [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL/). But my browser yells at me when I go to that uci.edu website on account of a security cert that expired nearly a month ago. That doesn't bode well for the contents of the site if the folks running it can't even manage to keep up a simple TLS cert.

Answer (score 1):

cgohlke's comment was right, the file I was using was called OpenGL.py changed the name and it worked fine

Comment: gotta wait 2 days to accept the answer:)))))))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).